# Whenever I use ALT-TAB, Firefox display freezes

Tags: unity, compiz, firefox, application-switcher

I installed Ubuntu 2011.04 from scratch a few hours ago. At first Firefox was working perfectly. Then I selected "Static application switcher" in the Compiz configuration.

From that time, whenever I press ALT-TAB, Firefox's display is frozen. As hinted by the changing mouse cursor, I can click on link and select text, but I can not see it.

If I restart Firefox or simply unmaximize/remaximize it, the problem is gone, until the next ALT-TAB.

What's going wrong? How to go back to the deafult (non Compiz?) application switcher?

*Note: I am using the proprietary ATI driver Ubuntu proposed me to install.*

Comment: The problem disappeared after selecting the Compiz "Static application switcher".

Comment: Answer your own question and then select it as the correct answer when you are able to.

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, thanks! [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would have liked to really solve the problem, but meanwhile here is how to avoid the problematic consequence: Select the Compiz "Static application switcher".

Comment: Ya but static application switcher sucks. The system should not crash just because the user wants to use a different option

Answer (score 0):

This is an answer **if** you didn't check your settings correctly. `Static application switcher` is a watered down version of `application switcher`. It is generally more stable than the latter as well. When I switched from `static application switcher` to the more powerful `application switcher` I started observing the problems you mentioned: windows became locked until I resized them. The problem went away as soon as I disabled `application switcher` (which is a shame because it is so cooler).

Word of caution: re-enabling `static application switcher` made my system totally unresponsive to the point where I had to hold down the power button. Afterwards, however, everything returned to normal, after reboot